# Firebase REST API Query Parameters?

Tags: firebase

Is it possible to filter data returned by the Firebase REST API using query parameters? I don't see it mentioned one way or an other in the docs, but the client libraries support it, so I'm hoping it's possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It might be a bit late to answer, but Firebase does allow querying data via REST.

You can use the `orderby` option together with `limitToLast`, `startAt` etc just like you would when using the SDK.

Checkout the [Firebase guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-rest-filtering) for more details

Comment: but how do you use the orderBy, if your endpoint doesnt have anything special to orderby. I just want the last entries, I dont have timestamp properties or anything.

Comment: I think that without `orderBy` the order can't be determined because of the nature of JSON.
If you need a "timestamp", push your records with a key (or some field) of timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

I fought a little bit to have it working.

I actually needed 2 things:

1. combine `limitToLast` with `orderBy` as mentioned by idan

   `URL getUrl = new URL( url + "news.json?orderBy=\"timestamp\"&limitToLast=5" );`
2. add a rule in the database to declare an index on this "column"

   `"news" : { ".indexOn": "timestamp" }`

Answer (score 0):

Firebase provides querying parameters. However, I don't think they are the querying parameters you are expecting them to be, which are ones that filter data. Firebase REST API provides querying options like auth, print, callback, format, and download. Check docs [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest-api.html)

Answer (score 0):

Without ordering by certain field, By combining params `orderBy="$key"` and `limitToLast=5` you can get the last 5 of inserted data ordered by it's key

The documentation can be looked at [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#orderbykey)

Answer (score 0):

Having this data in realtime db:

```
{
  products: {
    -someid: {
      name: "foo"
    },
    -othereid: {
      name: "bar"
    }
  }
}
```

Set the following rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ...  // read, write etc

    "products" : {
      ".indexOn": "name"
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can query based on `name` "field" the following way:

`https://<db-id>.firebasedatabase.app/products.json?orderBy="name"&equalTo="foo"`

Be aware of the `""` double quotes around values in the url.